# Why 10049 error occurs in udp communication even though ip and port are entered correctly

Tags: tcp, udp, port

```
DWORD WINAPI socketRead(void *lpVoid)
```

{

```
while (true)
{
    // UDP socket
    WSADATA data_s;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    // socket start
    int wsok = WSAStartup(version, &data_s);
    if (wsok != 0)
    {
        cout << "Can't start Winsock!" << wsok;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "start Winsock!\n";
    }

    // socket bind

    SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 
    SOCKADDR_IN serverHint = {};
    memset(&serverHint, 0, sizeof(serverHint));

    serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.69"); 
    serverHint.sin_port = htons(1480);                          

    if (bind(in, (sockaddr *)&serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "bind socket!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "can't bind socket!" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        // socket clean
        int wsokE = WSACleanup();
        if (wsokE != 0)
        {
            cout << "Can't cleanup Winsock!" << wsokE;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "cleanup Winsock!\n";
        }
        // return 0;
    }
```

}

this is my code. I want to do UDP socket communication using winsocket.
It is trying to do udp communication with another computer.

However, I keep getting error 10049 even though I wrote down the ip address and port number correctly.

The 1480 port I wrote down in the code is what I set arbitrarily. Do I need to do other processing on the computer?

When I use the same ip and port in the incoming and outgoing confirmation program called Ezterm, the values ​​come normally.

In conclusion, we want to receive data from "192.168.0.69".

Comment: *"we want to receive data from "192.168.0.69""* - `bind` is about receiving data **on** a specific address and not **from**. You cannot bind on an address which is not on the system.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to put the IP of the receiver in the bind function?

Comment: The address in bind must be a local IP address where data should be received or just 0.0.0.0 to receive on all of the systems IPv4 addresses.

Comment: I had to finish it by today because it was company work. It is 7 o'clock at night now. Thank you so much